# setState is giving error while updating state from nested child functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[LInk to sandBOx](https://codesandbox.io/s/budgetapp-x0rk5)

I am trying to update state more than once. how can I do this.
I have seen below method from other website but unable to use it.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)
```

Error:**Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**

```
state={
        incobj:[],
        expenobj:[],
        totalinc:0,
        totalexp:0,
        click:0
    }


    takeInp=(e)=>{
        if(e[0]==="Income"){
            this.setState({
                incobj:this.state.incobj.concat( [e]),
                totalinc:this.state.totalinc+parseInt(e[2])
            }) 
        }
        if(e[0]==="Expense"){
            this.setState({
                expenobj:this.state.expenobj.concat( [e]),
                totalexp:this.state.totalexp+parseInt(e[2])
            })
        }
    }

    deldata=(d)=>{
        let num=parseInt( d.substr(1,d.length));
        if(d.charAt(0)==="i"){
            this.setState({
                click:this.state.click+1
             })
             console.log(this.state.click, 'increased')
        }
        if(d.charAt(0)==="e"){
            this.setState({
                click:this.state.click+1
             })
             console.log(this.state.click, 'increased')
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: you need to show us some more code and a tip when you write code is to use a variable that describes what they are doing. Right now, none of your code makes sense.

Comment: @CyrusZei I have given sand box link too. sure, I will edit all the valriable names now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by an infinite loop. Your `App` component is the parent of `Income` and passes it the `deldata` method that updates the parent. The child functional component has this snippet that executes on every render:

```
if (Remov) {
    props.todel(Remov);
}
```

When `Remov` is truthy, it updates the state of the parent. Which causes a rerender of the child. Which updates the state of the parent. Etc...

Do not fire `todel` in your functional component, not even conditionally. Call this only in response to some event (onClick, etc).

Comment: I removed useState, and declared remov with "let" to update it using onclik. it's working, I am halfway there to complete.